# Split text from URL content

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get data from this URL into a format suitable for Excel but am stuck. With this code I've managed to get the data into rows but for some reason they don't correspond to the row #'s. Can anyone help?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#    
url = 'http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/hoopstat-daterange.pl?startdate=20181021&date=20181021&saldate=20181021&g=0&ha=&min=&tmptmin=0&tmptmax=999&opptmin=0&opptmax=999&gmptmin=0&gmptmax=999&gameday=&sd=0'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
page_request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_request.text,'lxml')

data = []

for br in soup.findAll('br')[3:][:-1]:
    data.append(br.nextSibling)

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(data_df)
```

print results:

```
                                                    0
 0
 4943;Abrines, Alex;0;Abrines, Alex;okc;1;0;5....
 1
 5709;Adams, Jaylen;0;Adams, Jaylen;atl;1;0;0....
 2
 4574;Adams, Steven;2991235;Adams, Steven;okc;...
 3
 5696;Akoon-Purcell, DeVaughn;0;Akoon-Purcell,...
 4
 4860;Anderson, Justin;0;Anderson, Justin;atl;...
 5
 3510;Anthony, Carmelo;1975;Anthony, Carmelo;h...
```

Comment: How does the data looks?

Comment: Added what gets returned after printing

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: The expected result would be similar to print results except there wouldn't be any blanks in column 0. That is what I'm having trouble solving.

Comment: I'm not getting any blanks in column 0. except the very last row

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason behind the last row of your `DataFrame` being empty is because of your parser. At the last position in the list, it still checks the next sibling after a break and appends an empty space into your `DataFrame`. This would do the trick:

```
for br in soup.findAll('br')[3:][:-1]:
    contents = br.nextSibling
    if not contents == "\n":
        data.append(br.nextSibling)
```